# Jaas não funciona com plugin maven do tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, jaas

Estou utilizando o `JAAS` pra segurança da minha **webapp**.
Só declaro um `JDBCRealm` do Tomcat normal, passando as credenciais de banco... segue o `context.xml` com a declaração do Realm:

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"

           driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

           connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://ip:porta;databaseName=dbname;user=user;password=pass"

           userTable="user" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="pass"

           userRoleTable="roles" roleNameCol="rolename"

           digest="SHA-256"/>

</Context>
```

Instalando o **Tomcat 7** na minha pasta e colocando esse context.xml na pasta `TOMCAT7/conf/context.xml` e colocando a lib do sql server na pasta `TOMCAT7/lib,` a autenticação com o `JAAS` funciona normal.

Ao tentar utilizar o plugin do maven, a autenticação não funciona.
Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <port>9090</port>
        <path>/</path>
        <contextFile>src/main/resources/tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
    </configuration>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mssql-jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Coloquei o mesmo **context.xml ** na pasta src/main/resources/tomcat/context.xml